# F1A COMPETITION GLIDER

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, airfoil, glider, glide-ratio

I am working on a school project. I have looked up the airfoil database. There is a wide range of airfoils I have tried to optimize for my glider to no avail. How do i choose the best airfoil for a F1A competition glider?

Comment: Technically, this is for [Drones and Model Aircraft](https://drones.stackexchange.com/).SE, but you are more likely to find answers here. Generally, at this level, just look at what others are doing for this class. Everyone tries to "optimize" their competition models. Now, had you asked about F1B, I would offer some answers off the top of my head...

Comment: Go ahead bro. I am designing  a free flight glider. That Idea you have can help me a long way